# How to check if ID in the URI is null and throw an error?

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I tried to check if a specific URL doesn't specified an ID

This are what I've got so far:

```
http://localhost:8082/orders/1234 ---- Success!
http://localhost:8082/orders/ ---- URL not found!
```

I want to throw and error something like "Id not specified!" not a URL not found.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Validation Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/validation/validation-connector)

Look at the "Matches Regex" section down.

I have not tried it 
Hope it may help

Answer (score 0):

the believe the best approach for you is to start using RAML. you can design the endpoint in RAML and specify what error to be thrown if the request is not a match.

```
/{order_id}:
    get:
      description: Get a Order by id
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: Foo
              example: !include examples/Order.json
        400:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: Error
              example: !include examples/Error.json
```

in the above RAML definition if there is no orders/{order_id} you will get a http 400 returned.

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom error handling and that will return error description alongside other required data

set  status code 400 in a variable, map fields as per below example.

ex:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "errorDateTime": "2019-10-10T14:00:46",
        "errorMessage": "The requested API cannot be found,  ID is not specified",
        "errorDescription": "Description: /orders"
    }
}
```